# how do I parse a url with php

Tags: php, parsing, url

I need to parse a URL in php for a facebook like button.  what I do now is this:

```
<?php
  echo curPageURL();
?>
```

but I have articles that are sometimes 2 or three pages long so I want to parse the url without the page number so that the like button is for the first page of the article.  Sometimes a page number does not exist either.

my url looks like this http://www.mydomain.com/23/My-Article-Title/2/

the 2 at the end is the page number indicating page 2.  page one of the article appears like this though

http://www.mydomain.com/23/My-Article-Title/

how do I parse the url in php to remove the page number if it exists?

so I would only want to parse it if there was a page number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 preg_replace('=\d+/$=', '', $url);
```

Comment: I'm sure all of the answers given would have worked I don't know enough about regular expressions to know why one would be better than any other.  but this answer was the most concise and it appears to do what I was looking for.  So I'm marking it as the answer.

Comment: @webb `preg_replace('=/\d+/$=', '/', $url);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression with [preg_replace](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
echo preg_replace('#/[0-9]+(/)?$#', '/', 'http://www.mydomain.com/23/My-Article-Title/34/');

// output: http://www.mydomain.com/23/My-Article-Title/
```

The above regex removes any `/` + `numbers` + `(optional) /` that appears at the end of the URI.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
 preg_replace('/^(.+[a-zA-Z]\/)[\d]*\/?$/i', '\\1', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = 'http://www.mydomain.com/23/My-Article-Title/2/';
$url_info  = parse_url($url);
$pathes = (empty($url_info['path']) ? array() : explode('/', trim($url_info['path'], '/')));

if (($len = count($pathes)) > 0  && is_numeric($pathes[$len-1]) )
{
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($pathes);
    echo "</pre>";
}
?>
```